# Loading Externals & Vendors in Webpack Files array causes tests to run multiple times

Tags: vue.js, webpack, karma-runner, webpack-5, karma-mocha

I'm upgrading from Webpack v4 to Webpack v5, and my tests are running 4 times. (only ran once in Webpack v4)

Narrowed it down to this `files` array in the karma config:

```
config.set({
    files: [
        {
            pattern: "public/dist/js/global/knockout-bundle.min.js",
            watched: false,
            included: true,
        },
        {
            pattern: "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
            watched: false,
            included: true,
        },
        {
            pattern: "public/dist/js/global/portal.min.js",
            watched: false,
            included: true,
        },
        {
            pattern: "public/dist/js/global/foundation.min.js",
            watched: false,
            included: true,
        },
        {
            pattern: "public/dist/js/models/user.min.js",
            watched: false,
            included: true,
        },
        {
            pattern: "js/tests/unit/modern.testContext.js",
            watched: false,
            included: true,
        },
        {
            pattern: "public/common/images/**/*.+(jpg|png|svg)",
            watched: false,
            included: false,
            served: true,
            nocache: false,
        },
    ],
})
```

If I remove these following first set of files, (all but the last `included: true`), then the tests only run once:

```
        {
            pattern: "public/dist/js/global/knockout-bundle.min.js",
            watched: false,
            included: true,
        },
        {
            pattern: "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
            watched: false,
            included: true,
        },
        {
            pattern: "public/dist/js/global/portal.min.js",
            watched: false,
            included: true,
        },
        {
            pattern: "public/dist/js/global/foundation.min.js",
            watched: false,
            included: true,
        },
        {
            pattern: "public/dist/js/models/user.min.js",
            watched: false,
            included: true,
        },
```

The problem is these globals are needed for this PHP SSR app. Many of the tests need this code/ these packages. I know it has something to do with the `included` flag being `true` for all these. However, we need all these to be included or else `jquery`, `knockout` etc will not work.

I have tried using `bowerOptions` in the karma config like so, did not work:

```
        bowerOptions: [
            "jquery",
            "knockout",
        ],
```

Note, also have `externals` in the `webpack` config section like so:

```
{
    webpack:    
        externals: {
            moment: "moment",
            jquery: "jQuery",
            knockout: "ko",
        },
    },
}
```

**How do I keep the externals, and not have the tests run more than once?**

The tests only run one time in Webpack v4.

--------------------

Here's the full setup:

**MAIN CONFIG:**

```
const applyDefaultConfig = require("./karma.default.conf");
const webpackTestingConfig = require("./webpack.config.test");

module.exports = (config) => {

    applyDefaultConfig(config);

    config.set({
        files: [
            {
                pattern: "public/dist/js/global/knockout-bundle.min.js",
                watched: false,
                included: true,
            },
            {
                pattern: "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                watched: false,
                included: true,
            },
            {
                pattern: "public/dist/js/global/portal.min.js",
                watched: false,
                included: true,
            },
            {
                pattern: "public/dist/js/global/foundation.min.js",
                watched: false,
                included: true,
            },
            {
                pattern: "public/dist/js/models/user.min.js",
                watched: false,
                included: true,
            },
            {
                pattern: "js/tests/unit/modern.testContext.js",
                watched: false,
                included: true,
            },
            {
                pattern: "public/common/images/**/*.+(jpg|png|svg)",
                watched: false,
                included: false,
                served: true,
                nocache: false,
            },
        ],

        proxies: {
            "/api/image/": "",
            "/common/images/": "",
        },

        preprocessors: {
            "js/tests/unit/modern.testContext.js": ["webpack", "sourcemap"],
        },

        webpack: webpackTestingConfig,

        reporters: ["mocha", "coverage-istanbul", "junit"],

        coverageIstanbulReporter: {
            reports: ["html", "text-summary"],
            dir: __dirname + "/../../../tests/_output/coverage-js/modern/",
            fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
        },

        junitReporter: {
            outputDir: __dirname + "/../../../tests/_output/junit/",
            outputFile: "JunitTestOutput.xml",
        },

        webpackMiddleware: {
            stats: "errors-only",
        },

        webpackServer: {
            noInfo: false,
            progress: true,
        },

    });

};
```

**DEFAULT CONFIG:**

```
const { Browser } = require("selenium-webdriver");
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = function(config) {
    "use strict";

    const hostname = process.env.JS_KARMA_HOSTNAME || "webhost";

    config.set({

        basePath: process.env.JS_TESTS_ROOT_DIR || process.env.APPLICATION_ROOT,

        hostname,

        frameworks: ["mocha", "chai", "sinon", "webpack"],

        plugins: [
            "karma-webpack",
            "karma-mocha",
            "karma-chai",
            "karma-coverage",
            "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter",
            "karma-junit-reporter",
            "karma-mocha-reporter",
            "karma-sinon",
            "karma-sourcemap-loader",
            "karma-webdriver-launcher",
        ],

        files: [],

        preprocessors: {},

        reportSlowerThan: 100,

        webpackMiddleware: {
            stats: "errors-only",
        },

        webpackServer: {
            noInfo: true,
        },

        exclude: [],

        reporters: ["mocha"],

        mochaReporter: {
            showDiff: true,
        },

        port: 9876,

        colors: true,

        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

        browserConsoleLogOptions: {
            level: "warn",
            format: "%b %T: %m",
            terminal: false,
        },

        browsers: ["Chrome_no_sandbox"],
        browserDisconnectTimeout: 60000,
        browserNoActivityTimeout: 30000,
        processKillTimeout: 10000,

        concurrency: Infinity,

        client: {
            captureConsole: true,
            args: [`hostname_karma_server=${hostname}`],
        },

        failOnEmptyTestSuite: true,

        customLaunchers: {
            Chrome_no_sandbox: {
                base: "WebDriver",
                browserName: Browser.CHROME,
                config: {
                    hostname: "chromium",
                    port: 4444,
                },
                
                "goog:chromeOptions": {
                    args: [
                        "--no-sandbox",
                        "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
                        "--headless=chrome",
                        "--disable-gpu",
                        "--remote-debugging-port=9222",
                        "--no-default-browser-check",
                        "--no-first-run",
                        "--disable-default-apps",
                        "--disable-popup-blocking",
                        "--disable-translate",
                        "--disable-background-timer-throttling",
                        "--disable-renderer-backgrounding",
                        "--disable-device-discovery-notifications",
                    ],
                },
                pseudoActivityInterval: 30000,
            },
        },
    });
};
```

**WEBPACK CONFIG:**

```
require("dotenv").config();

const webpackUtils = require("../../../webpack/webpack.config.utils");
const { DefinePlugin } = require("webpack");
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");
const VueTemplateCompiler = require("vue-template-compiler");

module.exports = {

    target: "web",

    mode: "development",

    devtool: "eval-cheap-module-source-map",

    plugins: [

        new DefinePlugin({
            APP_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.APP_ENV),
        }),

        new VueLoaderPlugin(),

    ],

    resolve: {

        alias: {
            main: webpackUtils.getAbsolutePath("js/main"),
        },

        modules: [
            "node_modules",
        ],

        extensions: [".ts", ".js"],

    },

    module: {

        rules: [

            {
                // for parsing .vue files
                test: webpackUtils.VUE_FILE_REGEX,
                loader: "vue-loader",
                options: {
                    compiler: VueTemplateCompiler,
                },
            },

            {
                // convert javascript from es6 to es5
                test: webpackUtils.JS_BABEL_REGEX,
                exclude: webpackUtils.VENDORS_REGEX,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        cacheDirectory: true,
                        cacheCompression: false,
                        presets: [
                            [
                                "@babel/preset-env",
                                {
                                    targets: "defaults, node >= 12",
                                    useBuiltIns: "usage",
                                    corejs: "3.25",
                                },
                            ],
                        ],
                    },
                },
            },

            {
                // for code coverage
                test: webpackUtils.JS_FILE_REGEX,
                exclude: webpackUtils.JS_TESTS_REGEX,
                use: "@jsdevtools/coverage-istanbul-loader",
            },

            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: "babel-loader",
                exclude: webpackUtils.VENDORS_REGEX,
            },

        ],

    },

    externals: {
        moment: "moment",
        jquery: "jQuery",
        knockout: "ko",
    },

};
```

**TESTCONTEXT:**

```
const importAll = (r) => {
    r.keys().forEach(r);
};

importAll(require.context("./modern/features", true, /\.(spec|test)\.js$/));
importAll(require.context("./modern/main", true, /\.(spec|test)\.js$/));
```

**WEBPACK UTILS:**

```
const resolve = require("path").resolve;

module.exports = {

    VENDORS_REGEX: /(node_modules)/,

    JS_TESTS_REGEX: /(\.test\.js|\.spec\.js|\.testContext.js$)/,

    JS_FILE_REGEX: /\.js$/,

    JS_BABEL_REGEX: /(?<!\.min)\.js$/,

    VUE_FILE_REGEX: /\.vue$/,

    getAbsolutePath: function getAbsolutePath(pathToFile) {
        return pathToFile ? resolve(__dirname, "../", pathToFile) : resolve(__dirname, "../");
    },

};
```